# Typescript trowing "No index signature" error on optional chaining

Tags: typescript

In typescript

```ts
const func = (str: string) => {
  const strToNumber = {
    account: 0,
    goals: 1,
    metrics: 2,
  };

  const number = strToNumber?.[str] || 0;
};
```

gives the following error:

> Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type 'string' can't be used to index type '{ account: number; goals: number; metrics: number; }'.
> No index signature with a parameter of type 'string' was found on type '{ account: number; goals: number; metrics: number; }'.

I kinda understand why it is giving this error, but at the same time I don't see anything wrong with the code, since I'm using optional chaining and any falsey value will fallback to  0.

What should I do to not get this error? Is there a way that doesn't involve using "as" or "@ts-ignore"?

tsconfig.json

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es5",
    "lib": [
      "dom",
      "dom.iterable",
      "esnext"
    ],
    "allowJs": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "strict": true,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "noEmit": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "module": "esnext",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "isolatedModules": true,
    "jsx": "preserve",
    "baseUrl": "./",
    "paths": {
      "@components/*": [
        "components/*"
      ],
      "@lib/*": [
        "lib/*"
      ],
      "@utils/*": [
        "utils/*"
      ],
      "@public/*": [
        "public/*"
      ],
      "@types/*": [
        "types/*"
      ]
    }
  },
  "include": [
    "next-env.d.ts",
    "**/*.ts",
    "**/*.tsx",
    "tailwind.config.js"
  ],
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules"
  ]
}
```

Comment: @not_python here you go: https://srcshare.io/?id=6151cd10070b538a8b6ebf2f

Answer (score 2):

You can give the `strToNumber` object a type like this:

```
const func = (str: string) => {
  const strToNumber : { [key:string]:number } = { // <--
    account: 0,
    goals: 1,
    metrics: 2,
  };

  const number = strToNumber?.[str] || 0;
};
```

Here is an example [Typescript playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/PTAEHkCcEsHNoHYEMA2BYAUAYwPYIM4AuoAZgK4JZRyKqgC8oAFEZAFyiuKwCUDAfKADemUKFwFirACo4AcmQC2AIwCmkBsNAhQAHgC0%200WNBIsuCoQ4AGADTGxsHKnwcAjPYwnQi1YRhYrqAATJ5iAL4A3JjGEkSgCEpqGowy8knqAPwAdADarAC6oAA%20xaDW0RhRMRg6AG74NToA6tCEABaghACeAA6qmHHE5JSaLP4cXAi8AsKxePFpCirqoBxCoLkA1qrdbFOwBWyJKxrhmhs6BkZeJmYWCFblYSZOLu4vYr7%200IEcocZqhh5pIEhkUpx-LJlskcvl-EVSuVKlEgA)

Answer (score 0):

You probably need to use a guard clause to assert that `str` is indeed a key of `strToNumber`, so that accessing `strToNumber?.[str]` will not throw an error. The guard clause can be something very generic, as such:

```
function isKeyInShallowObject<T = Record<string, any>>(key: any, obj: T): key is keyof typeof obj {
    return Object.keys(obj).includes(key);
}
```

Then you can use it as such:

```
const number = isKeyInShallowObject(str, strToNumber) ? strToNumber[str] || 0;
```

[See proof of concept here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=13&ssc=2&pln=11&pc=1#code/MYewdgzgLgBAZgVzMGBeGAKaAnAXDHASzAHMBKNAPhgG8AoGGUSWHAFRADkEBbAIwCm2NLQaMYAQ2CgkUfAAYANGMYkQEgDYR8ARmXiYPAVGyFg2mACZ9MAL4BuOmObQYYXoOHpCEANICATwBJMABlAAtNDRAAdwB5PgArAWAoLBNFAhMObn4hCgB%20LOwcjyEAbRwAXRgAH1qYeUcHJ0RkKEJwGB9-YLDIjWj4pJSoAB42EQAlFJBsABMxolJMiTAAykoMAGtA-DWAzJAk-DYyfF2A7ogYS5A4GCgAgAcBe5hjxNEASGxjBGwYBgCWSqQAdJcIBhPmQwcRgBoEPMBFDLmRmkA). An advantage of this is that you no longer need to rely on optional chaining in this case, i.e. `strToNumber[str]` will work, since your guard clause will handle the case where `str` is not a key of the object.

---

Alternatively, you can let typescript know that `strToNumber` is just a generic dictionary whose key is any `string` value:

```
const func = (str: string) => {
  const strToNumber: Record<string, number> = { ... };

  // Rest of your code here
};
```

[See proof-of-concept](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBAZgVzMGBeGAKaAnAXDHASzAHMBKNAPhgG8AoGGUSWHAFRADkEBbAIwCmeGACUBobABMAPEVIAaGGF6Ds1dPUaMAhsFBIo%20AAzyGWkiG0AbCPgCMprTB4Co2QsFswATI5gBfAG46M2ZoJRUhNAI3Dm5%20IQB%20ADoAbRwAXRgAH2yYI2CgoA).

---

A dirty but workable hack is a one-liner, where you simply force TypeScript to think that `str` is somehow a key of `strToNumber`:

```
const number = strToNumber?.[str as keyof typeof strToNumber] || 0;
```

[See proof-of-concept](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBAZgVzMGBeGAKaAnAXDHASzAHMBKNAPhgG8AoGGUSWHAFRADkEBbAIwCm2NLQaMYAQ2CgkUfAAYANGMYkQEgDYR8ARmXiYPAVGyFg2mACZ9MAL4BuOmObQYYXoOHp2XD0ID8AHQA2jiSEDAA1gIAniBwMFAxAA4C8QQmHNz8QgC6MAA%20BTDyjg5AA).

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer! This worked very well with what I was trying to do.

However, it honestly looks complex for what it does, but I guess that's the tradeoff with typescript.